# How to send a hyperlink in a django send_mail inside html_message

Tags: python, django

I want to send a hyperlink inside the send_mail in Django , i have set html_message to an anchor but it didn't work , when i am sending an h1 tag it is working fine.

Code:

```
  def sendEmail(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    print(email)

    html_message='<h1><a href="http://google.com">Click</a></h1>'

    send_mail(
        'Password Recovery',
        'Subject',
        'boutrosd@hotmail.com',
        [email],
        html_message=html_message
    )
    return JsonResponse(0, safe=False)
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by `set html_message to an anchor `?

Comment: The email message has to be structured like an html document to work proberly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python

Comment: @boutros you need to construct the html email and render it and then use that render html in ur send email.  Check below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466796/sending-a-html-email-in-django

Comment: @LavanyaPant I just did it and it worked when i put a <h1> but it didn't work if i put a hyperlink inside html please any help

Comment: @mostafazh i mean set the html_message to contain a hyperlink

Comment: @ger.s.brett i did it but it isn't sending an email when putting a hyperlink in html

Comment: @Boutros can you try opening the email from gmail.com or any other rich email client?

Comment: @mostafazh it is not sending at all when i put a hyperlink

Comment: @Boutros try adding fail_silently=False when calling the send_mail or print it's return value in the json response.

Comment: print(send_mail(
          'Password Recovery',
          'Subject',
          'boutrosd@hotmail.com',
          [email],
          fail_silently=False,
          html_message=html_message
      ))   @mostafazh it is returning 1

Comment: what email backend are you using? SMTP

Comment: @mostafazh i/m using smtp2go