# I want to send weekly emails in my Django app. Where should the code that pulls the data from the database and sends the email message live?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

The title contains the question - I want to send weekly emails in my Django app. Where should the code that pulls the data from the database and sends the email message live? I have seen examples of code that sends emails, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809547/creating-email-templates-with-django) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466796/sending-a-html-email-in-django), but it is not specified in which file it resides and what's its relationship to the rest of the Django elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295268/where-should-utility-functions-live-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this really depends on the purpose of your email-sending script. It's completely up to you.

But if it is supposed to be a complex code that is used to periodically send emails with data from multiple django apps' models in database, I would suggest making a separate app for it. There you can also define your complete logic behind the periodical sending.

On the other hand, if it is supposed to be a simple while cycle / cron-based job used for one app's purposes, it can be a single file inside of the corresponding app's directory (send_newsletter.py).