# How do I make text "bold" in email body in python?

Tags: python, django, email

How can I make text bold in the email body in python? I am using the following code to send mail :

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(subject, message, sender, [email], fail_silently=False)
```

I want to make some important text bold. Using the following code I have received the whole string as a message.

```
message = " Hi Customer,<br> Your OTP is <b>****</b>"
```

But it works when I try `\n` as `<br>`. What can I do to make the text bold?

Comment: It seems that send_mail has an html argument, see https://www.fullstackpython.com/django-core-mail-send-mail-examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Django DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types), html should be added as separate file, so it could be read with or without html (depending on what receiver is using, not everyone want html in emails). You need `EmailMultiAlternatives` with `attach_alternative` method:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'from@example.com', 'to@example.com'
text_content = 'This is an important message.'
html_content = '<p>This is an <strong>important</strong> message.</p>'
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

All credits goes to this answer [sending a html email in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466796/sending-a-html-email-in-django)

to make texts bold in email body you need to send a html body.

Try this:

```
from django.template import loader

html_message = loader.render_to_string(
            'path/to/your/htm_file.html',
            {
                'user_name': user.name,
                'subject':  'Thank you from' + dynymic_data,
                //...  
            }
        )
send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=True,html_message=html_message)
```

And the html file should look similar to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ user_name }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ subject }}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```